# How to forbid "00" or "0123-like" start of input in Android EditText, in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I have an EditText object with the numberDecimal input type. The input manipulation (e.g., calculation) is working ok, but inputs starting with "00" and "0123-like" (zero followed by a number, not the dot) are currently permitted.

How can I forbid inputs starting with "00" or "0123-like" (zero followed by a number, not the dot), in Kotlin?

Aftering googling and reading many similar questions and answers, I've tried TextWatcher and InputFilter, but can't really figure out a solution.

Comment: Hi There. Post samples of what you have tried so far and where exactly are you stuck ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `TextWatcher` and regular expression if the modified string is in the format 0, followed by a number, you can remove the last inserted digit and return to a string containing only the initial 0.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        val newText = s.toString().trim()

        // Check if the text is 0 followed by another digit, in that case remove the last inserted value
        if (newText.length > 1 && newText.matches("^0[\\d]+".toRegex())) {
            // Unwanted expression: remove last inserted char and reset the cursor position to show after the first character
            editText.setText("0")
            editText.setSelection(1)
        }
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
})
```

**EDIT**
If you need to apply the same `TextWatcher` to multiple `EditText` you could define your `CustomTextWatcher` class:

```
class CustomTextWatcher(
    private val editText: EditText
) : TextWatcher {

   override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

   override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

   override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
       val newText = s.toString().trim()

        // Check if the text is 0 followed by another digit, in that case remove the last inserted value
        if (newText.length > 1 && newText.matches("^0[\\d]+".toRegex())) {
            // Unwanted expression: remove last inserted char and reset the cursor position to show after the first character
            editText.setText("0")
            editText.setSelection(1)
        }
   }
}
```

And then add it to your `EditText`s with:

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(CustomTextWatcher(editText1));
editText2.addTextChangedListener(CustomTextWatcher(editText2));
...
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. However, after entering "00" to the input area, it changed to "0" AND the cursor is placed before the "0", making subsequent input placed before the "0", which is a bit unnatural. So I add a line "EditText.setSelection(1)" to let the user keep inputing following digits.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer to add your suggested fix.

Comment: When I change "editText.setText("0")" to "s.setText("0")", an error shows up: unresolved reference. Since I want to use this addTextChangedListener for multiple EditTexts, so it is preferable not to use the name of the calling EditText object in the content of addTextChangedListener. How to make it?

Comment: @KKH You should define your custom `TextWatcher`. See the edited answer.

Comment: Really works! Thank you for the big help.